# Error when running sails project in development mode on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, sails.js

I have created an Sails project and I able to run migrations and seeders properly when I connected to localhost mySQL database and AWS RDS instance database from my local system.

But when I have pulled the code on EC2 instance and tried command:

```
sails lift
```

It is giving me error while running migrations in `alter` mode.

Below is the error which I am getting:

> When attempting to perform the `alter` auto-migration strategy on
>   model `archive`, Sails encountered an unexpected error when performing
>   the `drop` step.  This could have happened for a number of different
>   reasons: be it because your database went offline, because of a db
>   permission issue, because of some database-specific edge case, or
>   (more rarely) it could even be due to some kind of bug in this
>   adapter.

Error details:

```
{ error:
   { Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
       at Handshake.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/ipts/ipts-backend-sailjs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:164:17)
       at Handshake.emit (events.js:182:13)
       at Handshake.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
       at Handshake._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/ipts/ipts-backend-sailjs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:129:8)
       at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
       at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```